# Strategy in Nodejs for combining multiple readable streams

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream

I am trying to solve a Nodejs stream challenge. I have read the node documentation on streams multiple times, and implemented different attempts to solve the challenge. Trying with both duplex, transform, readable and writable :)

I have multiple HTTP readable streams, and the objective is to send data to a single pipeline, with backpressure working. I think this picture helps explain the challenge:

[image]

Update (13. september 2017). After reading the documentation again, I am implementing a custom written duplex stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This represents a great usecase for a duplex stream, combined with manuel flow control of the HTTP stream.

I have written a custom duplex stream, where the readable and writable part, is structured like this:

[image]

If you are interested in the specific code for the duplex stream, please send me a PM.

The code could look something like this (but it's pretty old, and could probably be simplified even more):

```js
import 'rxjs/add/operator/skip';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import * as stream from 'stream';
import { logger, streamInspector } from '../shared';

export class DuplexStreamLinker extends stream.Duplex {
    public readCount: number = 0;
    public acceptDataCount: number = 0;
    public acceptData$: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
    public streamName: string;

    constructor(options) {
        super(options);
        this.streamName = this.constructor.name;
        this.acceptData$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
        streamInspector(this, this.constructor.name);
    }

    public _read(size) {
        this.readCount++;
        this.acceptData$.next(true);
    }

    public _write(chunk, encoding, cb) {
        const acceptData = this.acceptData$.getValue();
        if (acceptData) {
            cb(this.pushData(chunk));
        } else {
            this.acceptData$.skip(1).take(1).subscribe(() => {
                logger.silly('I dont fire...');
                this.acceptDataCount++;
                cb(this.pushData(chunk));
            });
        }
    }

    public endReadableStream() {
        logger.debug('DuplexStreamLinker@endReadableStream was called!');
        this.end();
        this.push(null);
    }

    public _final(cb) {
        logger.debug('DuplexStreamLinker@_final was called!');
        cb(null);
    }

    private pushData(chunk): null | Error {
        const ok = this.push(chunk);
        if (ok === false) { this.acceptData$.next(false); }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: do you still have the code related to this diagram?

Comment: Hi @SergioGutiérrez --> I added the code, but keep in mind it's reaaaallly old